# dimensions of a background image

Tags: android

i have an xml file with a scrollview.i would like to have an image for background but i tried it in many image size and it pixelates..what would be the best dimensions of the image in order to use it as background ?thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using fill_parent or wrap_content? your question is still a little unclear. try android:background="@drawable/ur_image" from res folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a style:

```
<style name="styBackground">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/default_background</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerCrop</item>
</style>
```

And apply it to every screen you want the background on:

```
<ImageView
    style="@style/styBackground"
    />
```

The centerCrop will guarantee that it doesn't stretch, and the fill_parent's cause the image to fill the screen, but not more than necessary. For pixelation, make sure your image is large enough to support the highest resolution on the market, like 854x480.